# find name of icons in control panel

Tags: java, c++, c, windows, jna

Is there a way to obtain the name of the icons in the Windows Control Panel, and find out their coordinates?

One more question - if I have an application running and that contains buttons, is there a possible way to obtain the name of the button, as in `string`?

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows Control Panel?  Some kind of a UI widget like a `JPanel`?  Be more specific.

Comment: "find out their co-ordinates" ? - you mean on the screen? Or do you just mean how to launch them.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330741(v=VS.85).aspx lists the "canonical names" of each control panel item. For example, `Microsoft.DateAndTime` for the one that sets your date and time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191(v=VS.85).aspx shows how to use WinExec (which you may or may not be able to use from Java,  I don't know) to launch an item given it's canonical name, for example

```
WinExec("%systemroot%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate", SW_NORMAL);
```

There is quite a lot of community content on that page, indicating that perhaps it's a bit trickier than the documentation suggests. I suspect that getting your code to work smoothly on XP, Vista, and 7 may be frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The Mail icon is missing from MS's list.

[This source](http://www.public.madeinengland.co.nz/what-is-the-canonical-name-for-mail-in-the-control-panel/) indicates that it's canonical name is "Mail".

Answer (score -1):

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776778(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: How is a link to the "Shell Developer's Guide" helpful? This answer needs to be expanded.

Comment: @Kate, I pointed Paktrick in the direction of a potential answer.  If I knew the answer, then I would give it.  You didn't answer the question either.  Should your response be down voted as a result?

Comment: OP asked for the way to obtain the names. My answer is a link to the names. Therefore it's an answer. The second part, to be honest I don't even know what the question is there. All of that has nothing to do with downvotes. If you're mad at my comment, and downvoting my answer will make you feel better, go ahead. I use downvotes to make the site better, not to change people's behaviour. I use comments to change people's behaviour. It doesn't always work.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote your answer because it's not a bad one.  If you were the first one to provide the answer that you gave, then I wouldn’t have felt the need to post mine.  I feel it's better to have at least one response that points the person in the direction of the answer instead of having no clue as to where the answer exists.  Most people don't even know at a high level what APIs exist for Windows.  I still don't believe my answer is "bad" but your answer is "better" than mine.  I upvoted your answer because I also believe in the stackoverflow system.